# Difference between maven and maven eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a problem with maven integration in eclipse. I have a maven project which I am trying to deploy to Jboss server from eclipse using jboss plug-in. Unfortunately it fails as one of the class cannot be found.

I have built the project in command line (ear file) and dropped it to deployment folder in jboss. In this case it works fine without any errors.

If I publish project from eclipse the one of the class cannot be found. 
I have done some digging already and the class is there (WEB-INFO).

Does anybody know how to go around this issue or what could be a root issue ??

Thanks

Comment: please post the maven command line that you run... also the eclipse command

Comment: Ok may be I am not clear enough, I use mvn clean install. This build an ear file. Then in eclipse I refresh projects then I use Project->clean and then Maven->Update Project after that I publish to Jboss using jboss eclipse plug-in. After that when jboss deploying the application there are some classes missing. As I said before if I drop the ear file it works fine

Comment: the maven update project, only update the project references in eclipse project... it doesn't generate the ear artifact.

Comment: Correct. The ear file is generated by maven-ear-plugin. My point is when the eclipse publish to jboss server it doesn't cope a file it copy the ear directory. For some reason when Jboss deploy the application, spring framework cannot find one of the source class. I have checked and the class is in the WEB-INF/classes directory as it is expected. So I am trying to understand what is wrong/difference between ear file and folder.